# How to re-use formatted text across multiple HTML pages using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, html, text

It's possible to re-use a simple text string across multiple HTML pages using JavaScript: `$(".x").html("text");` and then `<div class="x"></div>`.

But is there a comparable method for formatted text? Say I want to have bold text or indent certain words (or manipulate the text in other conventional ways). Can any of that be achieved with vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: So do you want to be able to bold parts of the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can

```
$(".x").html("This text can be <b>formatted</b>");
```

plain JS:

```
document.querySelector(".x").innerHTML="This text can be <b>formatted</b>";
```

Included in a JS file at the end of the page, then your pages will show it if the JS in included on a page with a tag with class="x

Comment: Cool beans. Didn't think it was that obvious :)